# asp.net mvc knockout do not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to launch knockout example in ASP.NET MVC but it does not work.
In result i see only

> Passenger name    Meal    Surcharge

knockout part not available. Why? How to fix this?

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>

<script>
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
</script>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th>
        <th>Meal</th>
        <th>Surcharge</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal().mealName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you call `ko.applyBindings` the whole DOM should be ready.

So you need to move your `script` block **after** your `table` (or more preferable to the bottom of your HTML):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>    

<table>
   ...
</table>

<script>
...

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
</script>
```

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#activating-knockout):

> To activate Knockout, add the following line to a `<script>` block:
>
> ```
>  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
> ```
>
> You can either put the script block at the **bottom of your HTML document**, or you can put it at the top and wrap the contents in a **DOM-ready handler such as jQuery’s $ function**.